# Pagination with firestore cursor using timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use cursors for timestamped paging, but it returns the same data on every call to the database.

This way I keep it in firestore

```
const xDate = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
```

To use the cursor I do it as follows

```
let consulta = db.collection('facebook_spa');
          consulta = consulta.select('xId');
          consulta = consulta.where('xEstate', '==', true);
          consulta= consulta.orderBy('xDate', 'desc');
          consulta= consulta.startAfter(xDate);
```

In **console.log()** it shows me the timestamp is in the following form

```
{                                                                                                                                                                   10:59:40
  _seconds: 1600439396,
  _nanoseconds: 705000000
}
```

Try this way. Here I want to page by date because I have tried to do it by id, but it is necessary to group it by date

```
let consulta = db.collection('facebook_spa');
              consulta = consulta.select('xId');
              consulta = consulta.where('xEstate', '==', true);
              consulta= consulta.orderBy('xDate', 'desc');
              consulta= consulta.orderBy('xId', 'desc');
              consulta= consulta.startAfter('', xId);
```

I want to display the Id of the data in descending order by dates but with pagination from a cursor, either with the xDate or xId field or both (xDate and xId).
xDate is saved with the firestore "timestamp" and xId is a single field. In other words, display all the most current data to the least recent and with paging.

Neither way allows pagination to be done correctly

I will appreciate your help

Comment: What data are you expecting the query to produce?  Please edit the question to show the actual data you're working with.

Comment: @DougStevenson 
Hi. I want to display the Id of the data in descending order by dates but with pagination from a cursor, either with the xDate or xId field or both (xDate and xId).
xDate is saved with the firestore "timestamp" and xId is a single field. In other words, display all the most current data to the least recent and with paging. Regards

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue too. The `xDate` field needs to be converted to a Timestamp object first.

So use something like this:

```
let consulta = db.collection('facebook_spa');
          consulta = consulta.select('xId');
          consulta = consulta.where('xEstate', '==', true);
          consulta= consulta.orderBy('xDate', 'desc');
          consulta= consulta.startAfter(new admin.firestore.Timestamp(xDate._seconds,xDate._nanoseconds));
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: `xDate` is already a Timestamp from the declaration: `const xDate = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()`.  [now()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html#.now) returns a Timestamp.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot. Regards